# parse platform - listening for login / logout events

Tags: angularjs, heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using the parse platform (migrated on Heroku).
Could it be possible to achieve something similar to Parse.Cloud.beforeSave or Parse.Cloud.afterSave but instead tied to log-in and log-out events?

Right now I have put an $emit in every piece of code with auth functions.
It would be great to achieve something a bit more generic.

Thanks a lot for your help

Alfo

Comment: I think the simplest way is implement Save/Delete hook of related _Session(Parse.Session). BeforeSave _Session -> before log-in, AfterDelete _Session -> after log-out

Comment: project with implemented listener(onLogon) that you are interest in :  https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/blob/master/ParseUI-Login/src/main/java/com/parse/ui/ParseLoginActivity.java#L166

Answer (score 0):

`BeforeLogin` was added to the latest version of Parse Server:

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/5445